# Create a custom index with product information

Tags: custom, index

I'm trying to create a custom index where I want to index product information. I having trouble finding some real good information about this.
Documentation or really good commented example needed.

I have googled a lot and just found some short example how to do this and a github module that has no explanation in it.

Any suggestions?

I'm using EE 1.12.0.2

Comment: what is means by custom index

Comment: I mean a custom index that appears in the index section System->index management. Eg.
[http://www.mexbs.com/creating-custom-magento-index/](http://www.mexbs.com/creating-custom-magento-index/)

This link could be a good answer if it was more info about it with a working example.

Comment: That's an excellent article. Do you have specific questions as to what's not clear about it? You should be able to write your own using this information.

Comment: Yeah, I think the article helps a lot but it would be nice with even more information with an example of a real working index to fully understand all parts.
I still succeded in creating my indexer module but it would have been even more easy with a fully functional example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also reading this article: http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/09/16/magento-index-seminar-video-guide.html you have the code and video step by step.